# Is such a condition possible for the provided group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

So I came across this question in Gallian's book where we have to prove that a group G is abelian when for every x belonging to G | $x^2=e$ where e is an identity element.

So while thinking about $x^2=e$ , I stumbled upon the idea that -
=> $x^2=e$
=>  $x\circ x=e$ | $\circ$ = binary operation
But $x\circ x=e$ will only be possible if $x=x^{-1}$ ($x$ inverse) because only then 
$x\circ x = x\circ x^{-1} = e$

So possible that $x=x^{-1}$ in this case ?

Comment: Yes..$xx=e\implies x=x^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what $x^2 = e$ means, that it is self inverse

Comment: p.s. try to use mathjax for questions here :) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/403329

Comment: @TheMathsGeek well I tried to use $x^-1$ for notation of x inverse but I wasn't able to raise 1 , it only raised - sign

Comment: Take the matrix $D=diag(1,-1)$, or $D=diag(-1,-1)$. What is the inverse in $GL_2(K)$? So certainly it is possible for $x$ to be its now inverse - not only for the identity.

Comment: Use curly braces to have exponents with more than one symbol in them, like so: `x^{-1}` The same goes for most commands that "do something" to whatever comes after, like fractions and square roots.

Comment: If you click the Edit button you can see how I reformatted your question.

Comment: For an example look at the reflections $\sigma:(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto (e_1x_1,...,e_nx_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $e_i=\pm 1$. They form a group and $\sigma^2=Id$ for all $\sigma$. The property you found gives that $xy=(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx$. Therefore, this group is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct! By definition, the element $x^{-1}$ is the unique element such that $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x= e$. Since $x(x) = (x)x = e$, we have that $x=x^{-1}$.

To show that this insight is instrumental in proving that $G$ is abelian, I’ll give you a hint!

> Let $x$ and $y$ be any two elements. We want to show that $xy=yx$. Since $xy\in G$, what can we say about $(xy)^{-1}$?